# Oracle parent child query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following parent child relationship in my input data. I need to pull final parent id for each child which is the child id without parent in this case child id 4 and child name d

[image: Input Data]

**Here is the final output :-**

[image: Output Data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with t (child_id, child_name, parent_id, parent_name) as (
select 1, 'a', 2, 'b' from dual union all
select 2, 'b', 3, 'c' from dual union all
select 3, 'c', 4, 'd' from dual union all
select 4, 'd', null, null from dual
)
select child_id, child_name, connect_by_root child_id fp, connect_by_root child_name fp1
from t
start with parent_id is null
connect by prior child_id = parent_id 
order by 1;
```